# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_affected_rows(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, bool given in

Tags: php, sql, condiciones, delete

toy haciendo un delete de la base de datos, el comando delete funciona pero me aparece el error

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_affected_rows(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Escuela\eliminar.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Escuela\eliminar.php(12): mysqli_affected_rows(true) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Escuela\eliminar.php on line 12

```
<?php
$codigoO= $_POST['codigo'];

require "conexion.php";

$conex=mysqli_connect($servidorBD, $usuarioBD, $passBD, $nombreBD ) or die ("no se puede conectar");

$sqldelete="delete from docentes where codigo = $codigoO;";

$resulset=mysqli_query($conex, $sqldelete);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($resulset)>0){
    echo "no se pudo eliminar";
}
else{
    echo "se elimino correctamente";
}
?>
```

lo unico que no parece funcionar es la parte del if
if(mysqli_affected_rows($resulset)>0){

Comment: Seguramente hay un error en la consulta. Si la columna código es alfanumérica, necesitas encerrar el valor entre comillas simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error te está diciendo lo siguiente:

> ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, bool given ...

que traducido e interpretado a mi modo en tu caso seria algo así como:

> la variable pasada ($resulset) debe ser del tipo **recurso de mysqli**,
> pero se ha encontrado un *valor booleano* en su lugar....

**¿Y eso porque te sucede?**

Bueno, resulta que haces esto:

```
$resulset=mysqli_query($conex, $sqldelete);
```

y si miras la [documentación de mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) verás que sus posibles valores devueltos son:

> Retorna false en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW,
> DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto
> mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query()
> retornará true.

Dada esa explicación, al ser una consulta del tipo `delete` tan solo puedes esperar una valor devuelto de `false` o `true`, o sea, del tipo booleano. En resumen, $resulset en esa consulta o bien es **false** o bien es **true**, pero **jamás** un *recurso mysqli* que es lo que espera la función `mysqli_affected_rows` como argumento.

**¿Y como lo arreglas?**

Pues consultando de nuevo la documentación, en este caso de [mysql_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php), verás en sus ejemplos que estan utilizando la variable que se asigna con el `mysql_connect` (en tu caso **$conex**) en lugar del $resulset de tu pregunta.

Por lo tanto, y finalizando esta explicación, diria que para solucionarlo debes cambiar esta línea:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($resulset)>0){
```

por esta otra:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conex)>0){
```

y espero que con eso superes ese error concreto.

Nota: Siempre consulta la documentación de las funciones que utilices cuando te den problemas. Los errores pueden asustar, pero siempre te están informando sobre el problema que tienes, y tan solo debes interpretarlos correctamente documentándote sobre ello.

Comment: me sirvio, gracias por la explicacion detallada.